# Variable Date Format for WPF DataGrid in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DateTime` field in a `List<>` used as `ItemSource` in a WPF `DataGrid` that I would like to format differently depending on the value.

If the `DateTime` value is within a year of `DateTime.Now`, I want to use `'MMM dd hh:mm'` as formatting, if it is beyond a year of `DateTime.Now`, I want to use `'MMM dd yyyy'` as formatting, and if is exactly `DateTime.MinValue`, then a wish that the cell in the data grid is blank.

This is the code that I have that currenly only shows dates with `'MMM dd hh:mm'` as format.

Is it possible to define this variable formatting directly in the XAML?

If not, how can I patch the formatting programatically in the DataGrid_Loaded event?

[image: Screenshot of the code's output]

```
   public class DeadlineItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Deadline {get; set; }

        public DeadlineItem(string aName, DateTime aDeadline)
        {
            this.Name = aName;
            this.Deadline = aDeadline;
        }
    }

    private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var items = new List<DeadlineItem>();

        items = new List<DeadlineItem>();
        items.Add(new DeadlineItem("Distant deadline", DateTime.Now.AddDays(500)));
        items.Add(new DeadlineItem("Near Deadline", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));
        items.Add(new DeadlineItem("No Deadline", DateTime.MinValue));
        // ... Assign ItemsSource of DataGrid.
        var grid = sender as DataGrid;
        grid.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

And the XAML is:

```
<DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deadline" Binding="{Binding Deadline, StringFormat=\{0:MMM dd HH:mm\}}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I'm new to WPF (just started playing with it this afternoon), so I'm still missing some points.  Is this a type conversion on the fly?  Would it affect DataGrid sorting (ascending/descending) by Deadline column?

Comment: You can find some info [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF). And yes, I haven't thought about it, but it will affect the sorting, because the column will contain String, not DateTime. Nonetheless you may try to use [TemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) with appropriate template and the same converter - should work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eugene mentioned, you'll want to use a converter.  First, you'll want to add a class that implements [`IValueConverter`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/):

```
public class DateTimeFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dateValue = value as DateTime?;

        if (dateValue != null)
        {
            var diff = dateValue - DateTime.Now;

            // Greater than 1 year, format as MM/dd/yyyy
            if (diff > new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                return dateValue.Value.ToString("MMM dd yyyy");
            }
            else if (dateValue == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                return dateValue.Value.ToString("MMM dd hh:mm");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, you need to reference the converter in your xaml file.  Something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TestWpf:DateTimeFormatConverter x:Key="DateTimeFormatConverter"></TestWpf:DateTimeFormatConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

Lastly, you'll change your binding to use the converter:

```
<DataGrid
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Margin="0,0,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deadline" Binding="{Binding Deadline, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeFormatConverter}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You don't need to worry about sorting, the datagrid will sort on the underlying date, not the formatted string.

Comment: What does the "TestWpf" namespace in <Window.Resources> in your example correspond to?  Is it the application namespace as in "namespace TestWpf" in the code behind .cs file for the xaml?  If I put my application namespace name, I get a "nameprefix not defined" error.

Comment: Just figured out that I need to add a xmlns:TestWpf="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" attribute to the <Window> element.

Comment: @Pep, yeah, the TestWPF was just the namespace of the project that I was using to, well, test the code.  You can name it however it fits in your project.

Comment: @WyattEarp Thanks! I had a similar problem and I ended up using a solution like this... but also it is worth noting that if possible people can also use .ToString('FormatSpecifier') at the source if you are building the dataset yourself...something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx